# Groovy/Java: Parallel processing of directory structure where each node is a list of subdirectories/files

Tags: java, groovy, parallel-processing, cloud, file-structure

Here's my current problem:

I have a directory structure stored inside a cloud storage somewhere. Under the *Root* folder, I have 1000+ subdirectories and each of those have a single subdirectory under them. And within each of those subdirectories, a single file exists. So a simplified diagram looks something like this:

```
                      Root
       ________________|________________
      |         |             |         |
   FolderA   FolderB  ...  FolderY   FolderZ
      |         |             |         |
   Folder1   Folder2       Folder3   Folder4
      |         |             |         |
    FileA     FileB         FileC     FileD
```

For each node, it has properties `type` ("directory" or "file") and `path` ("/Root/FolderB"). And the only way to retrieve these nodes is to call a method called `listDirectory(path)` which goes to the cloud, gets all the objects within that `path`. I need to find all the files and process them.

The problem is that with the way that it's structured, if I want to look for FileA, I need to call `listDirectory()` **three times** (Root -> FolderA -> Folder1) which you can imagine slows the whole thing down significantly.

I want to process this in a parallel manner but I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried doing it recursively by using `GParsPool.withPool` with `eachParallel()` but I found out that parallel programming with recursion can be a dangerous (and expensive) slope. I've tried doing it linearly by creating a synchronized list that holds all the paths that are of directories that each thread have visited. But none of these seems to work or provide an efficient solution to this problem.

FYI, I can't change the `listDirectory()` method. Each call will retrieve all the objects in that path.

**TL;DR:** I need to find a parallel way to process through a cloud-storage file structure where the only way to get the folders/files are through a `listDirectory(path)` method.

Comment: What about caching directory structure? The deamon process that scans directory structure each N min in background into some shared variable. And main process just instantly  reads the shared variable.

Comment: Having a background process is unfortunately a no-go (due to server restraints). I'm hoping to find a way to do this through parallel processing.

Comment: Is the name of `Folder1`, `Folder2` pre-determined, or is it effectively random?  Wondering if you can get rid of a layer of querying

Comment: It's already set. In the actual data, they're split into the dates so it'll be "09" for the first layer and "21" for the second. Due to the restraints, I can't change the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

If caching the directory structure in memory by using a deamon is not an option.

or caching the directory structure by initially creating a one time mapping of the storage structure in the memory and hooking into each add remove update operation to the storage and changing the database accordingly is not an option.

assuming the storage structure is a Tree (usually is) because the way `listDirectory()` works i think you are better off using [Breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to search the storage structure tree. that way you can search one level at time using parallel programming

your code could look something like this:

SearchElement.java - represents either a directory or a file

```
public class SearchElement {

private String path;
private String name;

public SearchElement(String path, String name) {
    this.path = path;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

ElementFinder.java - a class that searches the storage you need to replace the listDirectory function to your implementation

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class ElementFinder {
    private final SearchElement ROOT_DIRECTORY_PATH = new SearchElement("/", "");


    public Optional<SearchElement> find(String elementName) {
        Queue<SearchElement> currentLevelElements = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
        currentLevelElements.add(ROOT_DIRECTORY_PATH);

        AtomicReference<Optional<SearchElement>> wantedElement = new AtomicReference<>(Optional.empty());

        while (!currentLevelElements.isEmpty() && wantedElement.get().isEmpty()) {
            Queue<SearchElement> nextLevelElements = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
            currentLevelElements.parallelStream().forEach(currentSearchElement -> {
                Collection<SearchElement> subDirectoriesAndFiles = listDirectory(currentSearchElement.getPath());

                subDirectoriesAndFiles.stream()
                        .filter(searchElement -> searchElement.getName().equals(elementName))
                        .findAny()
                        .ifPresent(element -> wantedElement.set(Optional.of(element)));

                nextLevelElements.addAll(subDirectoriesAndFiles);
            });

            currentLevelElements = nextLevelElements;
        }

        return wantedElement.get();
    }

    private Collection<SearchElement> listDirectory(String path) {
        return new ArrayList<>(); // replace me!
    }
}
```